# Moment.js date difference is NaN

Tags: reactjs, date, momentjs

I am trying to build an app in React whereby a user passes 2 dates and the system will return the duration between the 2 dates in days. I have used the Moment.js Library and it's working properly for days within the same year but returning Nan for dates in different years. Below is my script:

```
<tr>
    <th> 9</th>
    <th>Dr </th>
    <th>Abel </th>
    <th>Jack </th>
    <th>abeljack@outlook.com </th>
    <th>26 </th>
    <th>2019-12-25 </th>
    <th> 2020-01-02</th>
    <th>{moment([2020, 1, 2]).diff(moment([2019, 12, 25]), "days")}</th>
</tr>
```

What can I do to get it sorted?

Comment: what version of moment do you have? in this example it's work https://jsfiddle.net/twqz57yL/. and in what kind of element do you insert this data?

Comment: Version 2.29.1 . I want to insert it in a table column

Comment: Have you the possibility to share a working snippet of code that return the NaN value? Because I tried your code, but it's work fine and for me there aren't errors

Comment: I have edited the snippet: 
This is the Github repo https://github.com/KudahShambare/cyf-hotel-react 
This is the site URL https://cyf-kudahshambare-hotel-react.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Month starts from zero when you are creating date with an array of number that mirror the parameter passed to `new Date()`. So using 12 is not a valid number for month.

```js
const date1 = moment([2020, 1, 2]);
const date2 = moment([2019, 12, 25]) // null, month can not be greater than 11
date1.diff(date2, "days") // NaN
```

You can pass the date as string to `moment`. moment will parse the date string for you.

from [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string
> matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches
> the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of new
> Date(string) if a known format is not found.

```js
const date1 = moment("2020, 1, 2");
const date2 = moment("2019, 12, 25");
date1.diff(date2, "days") // 8 days
```